# Magento 2.1.9 an error has occurred on the server. Please try to place your order again

Tags: magento2, paypal

I keep on getting this error for credit card processing option. I cannot figure out what's wrong with it. Is anyone else running into this problem?

I'm using Payments Pro from PayPal if that helps. My system is running on Amazon Lightsail Bitnami.

Comment: refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165333/magento-2-payment-gateway-howto-show-gateway-errors-in-frontend/174300#174300

Comment: Please add error in your Question.

Answer (score 0):

> vendor\magento\module-checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php
>   comment below line

```
throw new CouldNotSaveException(
                __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.'),
                $e
            );
```

> Replace in below code

```
 throw new CouldNotSaveException($e->getMessage());
```

This is a display exactly proper error.